# How to Add an Instance Annotation to an Asp.Net ODataFeed (V4)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am using ODataLib 6.6.0 and Microsoft.AspNet.OData 5.2.1 Nuget packages.

I have the following code which creates a custom serializer to add a custom annotation to a paged OData feed.  The code compiles and is called correctly, all the way through the point of adding the custom instance annotation.

```
namespace WebApiTest.App_Start
{
    using Microsoft.OData.Core;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using System.Web.OData.Formatter;
    using System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization;
    using System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization;
    using WebApiTest.Controllers;

    public class FormatterConfiguration
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var formatters = ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create(
                new CustomODataSerializerProvider(),
                new DefaultODataDeserializerProvider());
            config.Formatters.InsertRange(0, formatters);
        }
    }

    public class CustomODataSerializerProvider : DefaultODataSerializerProvider
    {
        private readonly CustomODataFeedSerializer _feedSerializer;

        public CustomODataSerializerProvider()
        {
            _feedSerializer = new CustomODataFeedSerializer(this);
        }

        public override ODataEdmTypeSerializer GetEdmTypeSerializer(Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmTypeReference edmType)
        {
            var serializer = base.GetEdmTypeSerializer(edmType);
            var feedSerializer = serializer as ODataFeedSerializer;
            if (feedSerializer != null)
            {
                return _feedSerializer;
            }
            return serializer;
        }
    }

    public class CustomODataFeedSerializer : ODataFeedSerializer
    {
        public CustomODataFeedSerializer(ODataSerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            : base(serializerProvider)
        {
        }

        public override Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataFeed CreateODataFeed(System.Collections.IEnumerable feedInstance, Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmCollectionTypeReference feedType, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
        {
            ODataFeed feed = base.CreateODataFeed(feedInstance, feedType, writeContext);
            var result = feedInstance as IPageResultCustom;
            if (result != null)
            {
                var value = new ODataComplexValue();
                var properties = new List<ODataProperty>();
                properties.Add(new ODataProperty() { Name = "CustomProperty", Value = result.CustomProperty });
                value.Properties = properties;
                feed.InstanceAnnotations.Add(new ODataInstanceAnnotation("org.CustomComplexValue", value));
            }
            return feed;
        }
    }
}
```

I issue a request to a feed including the HTTP headers `Prefer: odata.include-annotations="*"` and `Content-Type=application/json` in the request. Yet, I get no annotations in the response.

Tracing through the OData framework code, the internal property `Func<string,bool> Microsoft.OData.Core.MessageWriterSettings.ShouldInludeAnnotations` is never set when creating the `ODataMessageWriters` and therefore, the `ODataJsonLightValueSerializer.ShouldSkipAnnotation(string name)` method call always returns true.

It seems like a bug in the framework.  Am I missing something in my configuration or request?

**Edit Aug 7, 2014**

The issue appears to be related to the bug https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1880.

A workaround was suggested that involved creating a custom `ODataMediaTypeFormatter`.  However, `ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create` is not generic and recreating it involves too many dependencies that are internally scoped.  This workaround is a daunting task at a minimum.   It appears that the realistic limit of extensibility on `ODataMediaTypeFormatter` is confined to implementing custom serializers and/or deserializers.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It is a product specific question, not a question about the spec for odata which is how it now reads.   See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179969

Comment: Huh? What does the fact that it's product-specific have to do with the fact that "ASP.NET:" is, effectively metadata that you added to an otherwise reasonable title? The metadata is already present in the tags. Perhaps you'd like to edit the title to "How to Add an Instance Annotation to an ASP.NET ODataFeed (V4)"? Note that I left the "(V4)" in the title. It is metadata but there's no tag to substitute.

Comment: @RichardCollette can you explain better the IPageResultCustom implementation? I am copying your code and I don't understand how it is implemented that interface.

Answer (score 1):

I could get around this by setting the Preference-Applied in the response header by overriding DelegatingHandler.SendAsync like this:

```
return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(t =>
{
   var response = t.Result;
   IEnumerable<string> headers;
   if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("Prefer", out headers))
   {
      response.Content.Headers.Add("Preference-Applied", headers);
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is a custom message handler as discussed here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm hitting exactly the same problem, and setting the response headers doesn't seem to make any difference.